# Foreach loop multiple actions

Tags: c#, for-loop

```
for (int b = 1; b <= list.count; b++ )
{
    method1
    method2
    method3
    method4
}
```

I want to be able to run multiple methods on a for loop, however i need the statement to break as soon as it gets to the count. At the moment, b could be 24 (list 26) but there are still 4 methods remaining to run which will end up at 28. I need to put something obviously inside the for loop, not sure what though.

Comment: are you incrementing b in for loop ?

Comment: Requirement unclear have u used `break;`

Comment: are you adding items to the list? if so you shouldn't call Count every time in the loop as the latest count value is returned.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? The example you posted should be fine.

Comment: Never, *never*, **never** change the loop variable within the loop!

Comment: Are the methods altering the value of `b` or the contents of `list`? That is still unclear.

Comment: @NitinVarpe instruction unclear got stuck in virtual machine.

Comment: It would be nice to know the real problem what you are trying to solve in this way. I notice `list.Count` and I am very suspicious, what these methods are doing something like `list.Add` or `list.Remove`/`RemoveAt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int b = 1; b <= list.count;b++ )
{
   if (b <= list.count) method1();
   b++;
   if (b <= list.count) method2();
   b++;
   if (b <= list.count) method3();
   b++;
   if (b <= list.count) method4();
}
```

Comment: I think you should read what @Thorsten Dittmar has posted above. And in my opinion he is right!

Comment: Any specific reason would be appreciated

Comment: Why are you incrementing `b` between each method call? What does that accomplish?

Comment: @MattJones The variable b is incremented to skip below methods once it reaches list's length. I hope that's what the question needs.

Comment: In cases where b is used as an index to get an item in a collection, you increase the risk of OutOfRangeException to occur. b is a variable declared by the loop, let the loop increment it, you shouldn't touch it.

Comment: @MPatel Now I got the reason. But the user didn't mention anything about using variable inside the methods. That's why I answered it in this way

Comment: @RCkumar if there are 24 items in the list, your code will only execute the loop 6 times. You're completely changing the behaviour.

Comment: @MattJones I understood, "At the moment, b could be 24 (list 26) but there are still 4 methods remaining to run which will end up at 28", as           each method is counted as one loop.

Comment: This just got marked as answer accepted but I feel that this is very poor and very bad practice. Just because it works does not make it correct!

Comment: @MPatel,@Konrad Kokosa  Sometimes simple solutions are enough to solve simple problems. Always context determines a solution as good or bad. In this context, the above solution is enough

Comment: @RCkumar No offense but this is not a solution. This is butchered code.

Comment: @RCkumar, not agree, coding has some good and bad practices. Repeating code is bad one. Example: what if there will be 8 methods? 12? 20?

Answer (score 4):

Declare list of methods:

```
List<Action> methods = new List<Action>()
{
    method1, method2, method3, method4
};
```

And then use LINQ to iterate over:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, list.count)
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(i => (methods[i % methods.Count])());
```

or if you do not like LINQ, simply:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.count; ++i)
{
    methods[i % methods.Count]();
}
```

**Note**: Repeating `if (b <= list.count)` is ugly and unmaintainable...

Comment: I think hard-coding the upper limit into `Enumerable.Range(0, 25)` is unmaintainable too, particularly if the list is of unknown length.

Comment: @MattJones, Oh come on.. it is just example, you can take 25 from web.config or database if you like. Am I to write code for it too?

Comment: the upper limit appears to be from the number of items in the list, which is probably based on some other part of the app. Why not write code for it too if it makes the answer clearer? I thought that was the point of SO.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini, true but some people are LINQ-oriented

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution :D

```
for (int b = 1; b <= list.count; b++ )
{
    if (b <= list.count) method1();
    if (b <= list.count) method2();
    if (b <= list.count) method3();
    if (b <= list.count) method4();
}
```

Comment: Why not to call all methods in single if

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan as I understand each method increments `b` in some way (question still unclear)

Answer (score 1):

If you increment b in for loop then check and break for loop in between. Like :

```
if (b >= list.count) break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Look on **this example** for call method dynamic.
You need only one method call in your loop and you can define entire number of calling any methods from loop this way. (this example is runnable as new console applicaiton):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numberOfMethodCalls = 5;
        string[] charList = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };

        Console.WriteLine("Static calls --------------");
        for(int b = 0; b < numberOfMethodCalls; b++)
        {
            typeof(Program).GetMethod("Method" + (b%3).ToString()).Invoke(null, new object[] { b }); // call static method
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Calls for object ----------");
        Program p = new Program();
        for(int b = 0; b < numberOfMethodCalls; b++)
        {
            CallMethod(p.GetType().ToString(), "Method" + charList[b%3], b);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void CallMethod(string typeName, string methodName, int param)
    {
        Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);
        methodInfo.Invoke(instance, new object[] { param });
    }

    public static void Method0(int num) { Console.WriteLine("1: STATIC b=" + num.ToString()); }
    public static void Method1(int num) { Console.WriteLine("2: STATIC b=" + num.ToString()); }
    public static void Method2(int num) { Console.WriteLine("3: STATIC b=" + num.ToString()); }

    public void MethodA(int num) { Console.WriteLine("1: b=" + num.ToString()); }
    public void MethodB(int num) { Console.WriteLine("2: b=" + num.ToString()); }
    public void MethodC(int num) { Console.WriteLine("3: b=" + num.ToString()); }
}
```

After call you get 5 cals of methods each type.
**Result from console:**

```
Static calls -----------------
1: STATIC b=0
2: STATIC b=1
3: STATIC b=2
1: STATIC b=3
2: STATIC b=4
Calls for object -------------
1: b=0
2: b=1
3: b=2
1: b=3
2: b=4
```

So, you don´t need enumerate all methods, and you can call them dynamic defined by string.